# Motherboard will not boot

Tags: boot, motherboard

I just purchased an Intel DX79SR MB and an Intel i7-3930K CPU and a Corsair AX750 Gold PS.

With 32G G.Skill Ares F3-1866C10Q RAM and a Aerocool case. All parts brand new.

When I assembled the parts there was no power getting to the board. I tried the PS in another PC and it appeared to be working ok. I then went to the Intel site which suggested I try the board outside of the case as there may be a short. It made no difference. I stopped testing on the assumption that if it was a short I was not going to take the chance of damaging the CPU by further testing. I sent the board back to the supplier who replaced it with a new board. I have since reassembled the parts but I am having the same problem.

I am now completely confused. I have removed all the RAM and tried to boot but no luck. All of the internal fans and CPU fan does not rotate.

Would a defective CPU cause this problem?

Comment: Can you just confirm that the fan on the PSU spins (please don't be offended by this question, I know it's a simple/basic thing) and that all Molex cables are plugged in and you have the correct power requirements/plugs for the board.

Comment: make sure you checked the CPU power supply connector - its 4 to 6 pins, and people forget to plug it in VERY often

Answer (score 2):

```
All of the internal fans and CPU fan does not rotate.
```

Does power supply fan rotate? Test power supply in standalone mode.

First, unplug it from motherboard, internal HDD and DVD drive.
Then short PS_ON# pin with COM pin using unfold clip as shown below:

[image: Starting power supply without motherboard]

If power supply fan does not rotate after the short, then PSU should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was nearly identical but the difference is, when I booted up the motherboard would flash on (there were LED's on the board) and the CPU fan would spin (although maybe only once round).

The fault was my CPU was dead (and Intel were excellent and sent me the replacement).

I think the next step is to contact the company you made the purchase from. Now a days, it appears that companies prefer to just swap the board to keep customers happy and not test if the board is or isn't faulty. I would get in touch with them and ask them. Explain the same issue still persists and that it may or may not be the board.

It's not impossible that the batch of motherboards are defective (although it is doubtful).

Ask the company to test the board and confirm it works or not. See if you know any one who has the same chipset/size and use it (providing it is compatible). If they're a 'PC' company then you can send the lot back and say "test it" which they may or may not do (or may or may not charge for). If it is just a 'reseller' and no in house IT then you may need to take it to a computer shop and ask them to test out all components.